# Laravel 8. Seeder class does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, class

This problem is not new, but I’ve looked and tried all the proposed solutions in other threads with no success.
I’m working with Laravel 8 with Homestead, is a new installation on a Windows 10 machine, not an upgrade.
I’m trying to seed a file called *HotelSeeder.php*. When I run the command

```
php artisan db:seed
```

I get the next error:

[image: Error]

My HotelSeeder class goes like this:

[image: HotelSeeder.php]

My DatabaseSeeder class goes like this:

[image: DatabaseSeeder.php]

Both classes are located in the directory **database/seeders**

Autoload in composer.json goes like this:

[image: Autoload]

After I run *vagrant up* and *vagrant ssh*, the commands that I’m running are:

`php composer auto-load`

`php artisan db:seed`

And the error shows up.

I've tried also:

`php artisan db:seed --class=HotelSeeder`

`php artisan migrate:fresh –seed`

`php artisan clear:cache`

`php artisan optimize`

Nothing seems to work. I hope you can help me.

Comment: always put up code as text as it is text, not images

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your seeder class is named `Database\Seeders\HotelSeeder`. In your `DatabaseSeeder.php` file you should remove the alias for `HotelSeeder` as that is saying you want to alias a class from the root namespace named `HotelSeeder` which is not your class. If you remove that alias then the reference to `HotelSeeder` will actually be your correct class, `Database\Seeders\HotelSeeder` because the current namespace of this file is `Database\Seeders` so all class references are to that namespace.

Remove: `use HotelSeeder;`

Just a PHP namespacing thing.

Answer (score 5):

Try the command:

```
composer dump-autoload --optimize
```

then:

```
php artisan db:seed
```